# Lasso with SGL package : I get different results using the index parameter and alpha = 1?

Tags: r, selection, cross-validation, lasso-regression

I am working on the selection of variables in high dimensional models.
I use the SGL package of R. in the function cvSGL if we set the parameter **alpha=1** the function makes the selection of the variables with the **lasso method**. And the **index parameter is a vector indicating group membership of each covariate.**

My problem is: **If I set alpha = 1 and I put index (= to random values). I get a different result than alpha = 1 without index parameter.** While normally the function must give the same results!

Here is my code:

```
library("SGL")
library("biospear")
data("Breast")

data <- list(x =  Breast[,4:length(Breast)], time = Breast$time, status = Breast$status)
cv_SGL1 <- cvSGL(data, type = "cox", maxit = 100, 
                 thresh = 1e-3,  nlam = 20,
                 gamma = 0.8, standardize = TRUE,
                 nfold = 5, verbose = FALSE, step = 1, reset = 10,
                 alpha = 1)


index3 <- c(1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 4 , 4 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 2 )
cv_SGL.3 <- cvSGL(data, index3, type = "cox", maxit = 100, 
                  thresh = 1e-3,  nlam = 20,
                  gamma = 0.8, standardize = TRUE,
                  nfold = 5, verbose = FALSE, step = 1, reset = 10,
                  alpha = 1)
```

[image]
[image]

I will be grateful if anyone can help me!